# WiFi repeatedly asks for password (Ubuntu 12.10 fresh)

Tags: wireless

I'm sure the passphrase is correct 100% but Wifi keeps asking for authentication and never connects. What can I do? I've tried removing the networks, resetting the router, changing the password, rebooting Ubuntu, disabling IPv6.

Also, it worked until earlier today and then stopped. All my other devices log in fine.

Comment: How about assigning a static IP? Did you try that?

Comment: Still stuck at authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured the problem. My new Wireless keyboard/mouse were conflicting with the frequency of the hotspot. I changed the channel and it's fixed!