# WiFi asks for password again and again

Tags: networking, wireless, password, iwlwifi

**The Problem**

- My WiFi network disconnects itself randomly and starts asking for password.
- The password is already stored, I just have to click on connect.
- When I click on connect, it remains connected for some time then again disconnects and sometimes it even does not connects.
- The speed while being connected is very low and torrents are not downloading.
- When I sometimes connect to WiFi I get `System encountered a error` dialogue box

**What did I do**

- I go to `Edit connections` and make sure that `All users can connect is ticked.`
- I also deleted config file of connection from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-conncections`

I still can't connect to WiFi sometimes and it disconnects automatically if I'm ablee to get connected after some time. So what should I do?

After googling I found that this problem has been encountered in earlier versions, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 so if there is a permanent solution which can help everyone that will be the best.

P.S.- I have already tried these links:

- [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)
- [WiFi repeatedly asks for password (Ubuntu 12.10 fresh)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210961/wifi-repeatedly-asks-for-password-ubuntu-12-10-fresh)
- http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/285287/wifi-keeps-asking-for-password-ubuntu-12-10 .

Also the WiFi network works fine with my mobile.If more information is needed than let me know and how I can find it.

Also after seeing this [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into/61547#61547) i found that no card was soft or hard blocked and rest info I found after using commands are on http://paste.ubuntu.com/19615988/

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino
> Wireless-N 130 [8086:0896] (rev 34)
> Subsystem: Intel Corporation
> Centrino Wireless-N 130 BGN [8086:5005]   Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

**New Update:** I can't connect to my WiFi network, I have to use USB tethering in mobile to use internet on my laptop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Run `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"`, reboot and test again.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks it worked. Can you write a answer so that I can accept it and it will also help others and please mention what does this command did?

Comment: There are a few adapters that do not support this protocol. This solution is applicable to all of them. I could not find an wxact duplicate, so I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These adapters do not support 802.11n protocol well (at least on linux), but `iwlwifi` driver tries to use it. You can disable this protocol by running in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

This will be applied after a reboot.

Comment: This is my output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` -> `02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
 Kernel driver in use: wl`. What should I use?

Comment: This is a different device and unrelated to this case.

Comment: Yeah, but I am facing the same issue.

Comment: You can always ask a new question.

Comment: Here is it, https://askubuntu.com/q/1234382/1053060

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and after scouring the internet for a solution, I found out it was a problem with recent versions of `wpa_supplicant`.
Worth a try. Hopefully downgrading will help someone out there.

**EDIT**: I'm currently using `wpa_supplicant 2.1`.

Comment: Is this still relevant in 2024?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here in Ubuntu 22.04 on DELL Latitude E6530, but the solution didn't work. I had to write it to the same file as in the solution above, but without the suffix '-opt':

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```