# Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 won't connect, keeps asking for password

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I'm on Kubuntu 16.04, all packages up to date.

Yesterday, out of the blue (not after a reboot or anything), my WiFi stopped working. The hardware is still working, I am able to connect over Ethernet, and all the local WiFi networks are listed in the NetworkManager widget. But when I try to connect to my WiFi network, it says "Configuring interface...", asks for a password, stalls for a moment, asks again, and so on, over and over again, never connecting.

I have already rebooted many times, installed all updates, and tried deleting and adding the connection, marking the connection as "Available to all users", and disabling `kwallet`.

**EDIT:**
Here's the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4062]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

The fix from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799301/wifi-asks-for-password-again-and-again), suggested by user68186, works for me (I'm able to connect to WiFi, thank you!).

So here's my updated question: is there a way for me to make WiFi work without disabling 802.11n speeds?

Comment: @user68186: Thanks, I'd missed that one in my searches. I'll test, if it works, we can close as duplicate.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6: Will do, once computer finishes restarting.

Comment: Make sure that you're using WPA2-AES in router. Reboot your wireless router. Delete/re-add the wireless profile again if need be.

Comment: @heynnema: The router is using WPA2-AES, every other device in the house still works.

Comment: Only takes a couple of minutes to reboot the router. I'd still try it.

Comment: @heynnema: I can't disconnect everyone else right now, but I will when I have a chance.

Comment: @Pilot6: I added the info and updated my question; thank you for your solution from the other question.

Comment: You can try that command using `11n_disable=8`, then if it does not fix `11n_disable=4`. That will not fully disable the 802.11n. This adapter poorly supports it.

Comment: @Pilot6: `11n_disable=8` is working so far, thank you. If you add an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Did you reboot after you entered the command? It requires a reboot to apply.

Comment: @Pilot6: Yes. Currently running with `11n_disable=8` in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf` after reboot.

Comment: But... what kind of connection speed are you getting after adding the 11n_disable parameter?

Comment: I am writing an answer. The speed should be normal for 802.11n.

Comment: @heynnema: According to Google's speed test, I'm getting 47.5 Mbps download right now, which sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a kernel module option. Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"
```

and reboot.

That sets the `enable agg TX` option for the `iwlwifi` module. This is required for this adapter to work in 802.11n mode well.

Comment: If these are similar problems, can we consolidate these to one question possibly with multiple answers for different WiFi chips? Thanks

Comment: What kind of different chips you mean? This solution is specific to some Intel adapters.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the other [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/799301/wifi-asks-for-password-again-and-again) carefully enough and assumed they were different chips. Why `11n_disable=8` in one and  `11n_disable=1` in the other?

Comment: `11n_disable=1` disables the `n` mode. It is guaranteed to fix the issue. `8` does not disable anything but enables `agg TX` whatever this means. It may also fix it.