# Ubuntu 16.04, Wifi connected, no data. Wired connection works

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, atheros

I have a ubuntu 16.04, windows 10 asus dual boot.

I saw a similar (but not the same) question posted to this one at this link: [Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 won't connect, keeps asking for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881674/intel-centrino-wireless-n-2230-wont-connect-keeps-asking-for-password).

My wireless connects but no data is transferred, I can't load google, etc. I typed in:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

And received:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565  / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] rev(01)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0662]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules : ath9k
```

I tried the fixes suggested, but I do not have the `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf` file, only a  `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file. I tried to adapt for atheros vs. intel, but I lack the proper know how.

What should my next steps be?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
I entered the following command as suggested by user nadav mavor:

`sudo ifconfig -a ping 8.8.8.8`

I received:

```
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
ping: Error while getting interface flags: No such device
```

**Edit 2:**
Corrected the command inputs. I entered:

`sudo ifconfig`

and received:

```
enp2s0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:62:66:1d:ac
       UP broadcast multicast MTU: 1500 metric:1
       RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       collisions: 0 txqueuelen:1000
       RX bytes:0 (0.0B) TX bytes:0 (0.0B)
lo     Link encap:local loopback\
       inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
       inet6 addr:1/128 Scope:Host
       UP Loopback Running MTU: 65536 metric:1
       RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       collisions: 0 txqueuelen:1
       RX bytes:632 (632.0B) TX bytes:632 (632.0B)
wlp3s0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 18:cf:5e:d2:63:df
       inet addr:10.121.131.95 Bcast:10.121.143.255 Mask:255.255.240.0
       inet6 addr:fe80::cae7:ed2b:584a:84cb/64 Scope:Link
       UP Loopback Running MTU: 1500 metric:1
       RX packets:6002 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:3663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       collisions: 0 txqueuelen:1000
       RX bytes: 8134153 (8.1MB) TX bytes: 421410 (421.4KB)
```

entered `sudo ping -c2 8.8.8.8` and received:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) byts of data
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 times=38.4ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 times=13.9ms
--8.8.8.8 ping statistics

2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.998/26.201/38.405/12.204 ms
```

I entered `sudo iwconfig` and received:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID "internetname"
          mode:managed frequency: 2.412 GHZ Access Point: 84:D4:7e:01:A0
          bit rate=65Mb/s Tx-Power = 17dBm
          retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:on
          power management:off
          Link Quality=50/70 Signal level=-60dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0   invalid misc:0 Missed beacon:0

enp2s0    no wirless extensions

lo        no wireless extensions
```

**Edit 3:**
For running `sudo cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.con`, I receive:

```
 # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)

 #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
 nameserver 127.0.1.1

 search "educationalinstitution".edu
```

Comment: It will make no good if you try solutions written for Intel to fix your Atheros issue.

Comment: can you add the output of the follow commands : ifconfig -a ping 8.8.8.8  and iwconfig

Comment: I tried to adapt them as I could. But I didn't know enough. thats why I'm posting here

Comment: @NadavMavor I enterred your commmands, and wrote the output back in an edit

Comment: one command at time  "ifconfig -a" then "ping -c2 8.8.8.8" and last "iwconfig" all using sudo

Comment: @NadavMavor I wrote the outputs

Comment: @NadavMavor I put he putputs in edit 2

Comment: can you please add the output of the following command: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: ok so you get internet working next step will be to see how your DNS is setup can you give the output of "sudo cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf"

Comment: @hamiheim no point to look at /etc/resolv.conf all the new distro stop using it

Comment: @NadavMavor I put the output in an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok its clear that you didn't get DNC from your network the fast and easy was of fix will be to just add by heand :

1) as root edit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base and put

nameserver 10.11.12.83
nameserver 208.67.222.222

it will add 2 name servers to your system (google one and openDNS one )

2) restart your network "/etc/init.d/networking restart"
3) test the new DNS "ping -c2 google.com"

new your system can work and your next step is to talk to your network manager to see why your system do not geting the proper DNS config

Comment: Thanks! will this fix work when im on other wifi connections?  Its been a problem at home and at work (different wifis). thanks again!

Comment: Hi nadav, this happened again, the file still shows those two servers, but it won't work on a different Wi-Fi now. Is there a permanent fix for This?