# Ubuntu 20.04 - Wifi Automatically connects and disconnects

Tags: networking, broadcom, 20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. My wifi is connecting and disconnecting automatically. In fact, sometimes it does not even connect an I had to use and external card even that is troubling alot. It keeps asking again and again for my wifi password. I also had this problem with ubuntu 18.04. My router is all fine and wifi works for other devices. I have noticed that it only happens with poor connections mostly.

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 05
       serial: ec:f4:bb:83:06:73
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 34:23:87:dc:89:a7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:c0500000-c0507fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: wlx000f020260af
       serial: 00:0f:02:02:60:af
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=5.4.0-28-generic firmware=0.36 ip=192.168.10.9 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

And `lspci | grep -i network`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Is there any solution.

Comment: This must be a hardware issue. The correct driver is installed and there is nothing to tune there.

Comment: But, it worked fine for windows in dual boot.

Comment: I have the same issue. It works perfectly in Win and when I use an ethernet cable, but the wifi goes on and off from my Ubuntu 20.04. My modem/router is a Sagemcom Fast 5250

Comment: same here... on Thinkpad T440

Comment: completely same here lenovo ideapad

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue, on a Lenovo Thinkpad E540. Windows on the same laptop is not facing this. In my case, the output of `lspci` is `Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)`

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem today and I fixed it with **[BroadcomInstaller](https://github.com/mehedihshakeel/)**.

Here is how to apply the solution:

```
cd ~/Desktop
git clone https://github.com/mehedihshakeel/BroadcomInstaller2017.git
cd BroadcomInstaller2017
chmod +x ./Broadcom.sh
./Broadcom.sh
```

You will get the following options:

1. Install Wifi Driver
2. Show Commands
3. Quit Please enter your choice:

Select 1 (Install Wifi Driver) and wait for the Installer to finish.

This was tested on Kali linux.

Comment: The script is no longer available at that URL.

Comment: I found this script, but I don't know if it's the same one: https://github.com/alokblackhat/BroadcomInstaller2017